# Datatable not showing features when database used for retrieving data

Tags: ajax, datatables

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th hidden>ID</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){ retrieve_user() });
```

When i retrieve data from database the features is not shown. and if i click the button for export from the datatable feature, it doesnt show data

```
function retrieve_user(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'../conn/callFunc.php',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
      _trans:'retrieve_user'
    },
    success:function(msg){
    $(function () {
      $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
    })
        $("#datatable-buttons tbody").html(msg);

          }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: If i manually add data to the table there is no problem.

Comment: `$("#datatable-buttons tbody").html(msg)` is wrong, you should always go through the API or alterantvely reinitialise the table.

Comment: I don't quite really know other ways on how to retrieve data since im always using ajax and getting data like this.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about using the API instead of `html(msg)`, where your data come from does not matter; how you should use the API depend on what `msg` contain. Can you post an example?

Comment: I've put my code. Can you help me sir?

Comment: Hey, I just meant an example of the output, i.e what `msg` contain in your success handler :) Please do not "sir" me, and please remove the answer. Answers should only be real answers, not followups, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47374398/edit) the question to add an example of `msg` or if it is not too long, post it as a comment. If you are not deleting the answer yourself, it will be deleted eventually by a moderator.

Comment: But based in the now deleted followup, use `var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({});` ... `table.rows.add( $(msg) ).draw();` ...

Comment: I'm sorry I took so long to respond, got some errands to do. Thank you so much it works now. But, I got error about requested unkown parameter 0 ..... I'll be searching for some fix on it on google. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Perhaps there is discrepancy between the number of header `<th>`'s and the number of columns in each `<tr>` you are trying to insert.

Comment: I think there is no discrepancy between them. I have this null data that is inserted on first row before my retrieved data.

Comment: Well, in the code above you have 5 `<th>`'s, in the code you posted in the (now deleted) answer below you had 4 `<td>`'s per row ...It does not matter if you mark a header `<th>` hidden, you will still need to provide something to insert, otherwise you have bad markup. Browsers tend to ignore or fix bad markup under the hood in order to make the overall DOM and page look good, but DataTables play by the numbers, since features like sorting would be impossible if the table not is built correct.

Comment: I've edited it now, sorry for that. The problem is i have this null data in my first row and i don't know where it came from.